# Why service [@Injectable()] keep listening functions in angular.?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm just checking whether user is `loggedin` or not from service, but why it keeps listening the functions.?

```
loggedin(){
  const adminvalue = localStorage.getItem('user')
  console.log(adminvalue)
  if(adminvalue){
    return true
  }
  else {
    return false
  }
}
```

The adminvalue keeps printing in console.

Why route to check page.?

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="login()" *ngIf="!service.loggedin()">Login</button>
<button (click)="logout()" *ngIf="service.loggedin()">Logout</button>
```

See in [stackblitz console](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fh9vtn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: If you call a method from your template it will called infinitly.. That's why this is happening. you can find a good explanation in here. 
https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16

Comment: `service.loggedIn() `is called in every change detection run.

Comment: your function is called on every change detection cycle. and angular runs x2 cycles in development mode